# How to Solve the Coupled Differential Equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I came across the set of following coupled equations while studying cycloid motion in Griffiths' *Intro to ED*

$\ddot{y}=\omega \dot{z}$

$\ddot{z}=\omega (\frac{E}{B}-\dot{y})$

I am at a loss as to how I may approach the problem to solve. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I have posted the question there as well.

Comment: Just a remark : If you want to ask a physics question linked to differential equations, precise the physical context. If you don't do that, it becomes a mathematical question.

Comment: Substitution is the way to go, I think. Differentiate both equations and substitute for either $y$ or $z$.

Comment: Make a variable change : $y = A + \frac{E}{B}t + Y$, then differentiate the first equation, and using the second equation, you will get a very well known differential equation between $\dddot Y$ and $\dot Y$, that you can solve. So you get $ \dot Y$, then $ Y$,  then $y$. With $\ddot y$, you get $\dot z$  then $z$

Comment: Thank you. I have solved it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Coupled differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1652933/coupled-differential-equation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $q=\dot{y}$.  Then

$$\ddot{q} = \omega \ddot{z} = \omega^2 \left ( \frac{E}{B}-q\right)$$

or

$$\ddot{q}+\omega^2 q = \frac{E}{B} \omega^2$$

Can you solve this?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I can. I have to replace (q-E/B)  by q' then it's well known eqn.

Comment: @ArijeetDutta: that's one way to do it, sure.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the help.